# Finding number of roads

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> There are three cities $a,b,c$.  Each of these cities is connected 
>   with the other two cities by at least one direct road. If a traveler
>    wants to go from one city to another city, she can do so either 
>   by traversing a road connecting the two cities directly or by
>    traversing two roads, the first connecting the origin to the third 
>   city and the second connecting the third city to destination. In all,
>    there are $33$ routes from $a$ to $b$, including through $c$.  Similarly,
>    there are $23$ routes from $b$ to $c$, including $a$.  How many roads
>    are there from $a$ to $c$ directly?

$\color{green}{a.)\ 6}  \\
b.)\  3   \\
c.)\  5   \\
d.)\  10  $

[image]

From the question I get

( $a$ to $b$ +$\ a$ to $c$ to $b$ )  $\  n(ab)+n(bc)+n(ac)=33$

($b$ to $c$ +$\ b$ to $a$ to $c$)   $\  n(ab)+n(bc)+n(ac)=23$

I don't know how to proceed

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$ grade

Answer (score 4):

Let $x$ be the number of roads from $a$ to $b$, $y$ be the number from $a$ to $c$, and $z$ be the number from $b$ to $c$.  What you're told, when expressed mathematically, is that

$$x+yz=33$$
and
$$z+xy=23$$

and you're asked to find $y$.  If you subtract the second equation from the first, you get

$$(z-x)(y-1)=10$$

which implies $y=2$, $3$, $6$, or $11$.  On the other hand, *adding* the two equations gives

$$(x+z)(y+1)=56$$

and this limits $y$ to be either $3$ or $6$, since $56$ is not divisible by $2+1=3$ or $11+1=12$.  However, $y=3$ implies $z-x=5$ and $x+z=14$, which cannot be simultaneously satisfied by integers, since $x$ and $z$ need to have opposite parity to satisfy the first and equal parity to satisfy the second.  So that leaves $y=6$ as the only possibility, with $z-x=2$ and $x+z=8$ satisfied by $x=3$ and $z=5$.

Comment: A note to anyone comparing my answer to mathlove's:  We're using the same variables, but with $y$ and $z$ reversed in meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x,y,z$ be the number of roads from $a$ to $b$, from $b$ to $c$, from $c$ to $a$ respectively.

Now we have
$$33=x+yz,\qquad 23=y+xz$$

(Note that $33=x+y+z, 23=y+x+z$ are not correct.)

Thus, we have
$$33z=xz+yz^2=(23-y)+yz^2$$$$\Rightarrow 33z=23-y+yz^2$$$$\Rightarrow y=\frac{33z-23}{z^2-1}$$
Note here that $y$ has to be a non-negative integer. (set each of $z=6,3,5,10$)

Comment: Using partial fractions to write $y={5\over z-1}+{28\over z+1}$ might be a nice way to finish things off.

Answer (score 3):

Your equations can't be right, since you're getting two different numbers for the same sum.

The numbers of roads on the two parts of the longer leg have to be [multiplied, not added](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), since you can combine any two of them. Thus

$$
n_{ab}+n_{bc}n_{ac}=33\;,\\
n_{bc}+n_{ac}n_{ab}=23\;.
$$

Subtracting the two equations yields

$$
(n_{bc}-n_{ab})(n_{ac}-1)=10\;.
$$

Since each pair of cities is connected by at least one road, $n_{ac}\ne0$, so both factors on the left are positive. There are only four ways to distribute the factors of $10$ over the two factors: $1\cdot10$, $2\cdot5$, $5\cdot2$ and $10\cdot1$. For each one, you can solve, say, the first equation for, say, $n_{ab}$. For instance the factorization $1\cdot10$ yields $n_{ac}=11$ and $n_{bc}=n_{ab}+1$, and thus $n_{ab}+(n_{ab}+1)11=33$, or $12n_{ab}=22$, which has no integer solution. The other three factorizations lead to $7n_{ab}=21$, $4n_{ab}=18$ and $3n_{ab}=13$, respectively. The only one yielding an integer solution is $7n_{ab}=21$, corresponding to the factorization $2\cdot5$ and thus to $n_{bc}=n_{ab}+2$ and $n_{ac}=6$ (and thus $n_{ab}=3$ and $n_{bc}=5$).